# How to properly implement Multi-threading in a JavaFX MVMM application

Tags: java, javafx, mvvm

I'm looking for a way to thread the ViewModels in a MVVM Architecture, without having to use tasks everywhere.

My ideal solution would be :

- 1 Application Thread (with the view)
- 1 Background Thread (with the viewModel)
- Message passing between the 2
- ViewModels still behave as normal Java Classes w/o Tasks/Service/Platform.runlater in every method

Is there a way to do this without bloating the code ?

Comment: Did you try to adapt [JacpFX](https://github.com/JacpFX/JacpFX), [afterburner.fx](https://github.com/AdamBien/afterburner.fx), or [WorkbenchFX](https://github.com/dlsc-software-consulting-gmbh/WorkbenchFX) to achieve your goal?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not going to work the way you would like it to work. The view-models normally communicate with the views via bound properties. Therefore the properties of the view-models must always be updated on the application thread.
The proposed JavaFX way of dealing with concurrent background activities is to use Services. But if you don't like that it maybe worth it to have a look here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaFX

Comment: I did not know Properties had to be updated on the application thread, in that case it seems to me it will be hard to bypass the Services. I actually use a Utility layer between the ViewModel and Model layer, where most of the heavy computation takes place, so maybe I can find a way there. I'll look into what you're suggesting, otherwise I'll make use of Services.

Comment: Although, my issue with services is that there is not the syntax, but the fact that a clear boundary between which tasks need to be put in services and which don't doesn't exist. My search for an alternative solution is mainly a search for a consistent solution for all background tasks, not just the comparatively heavy ones.